# how to get a particular field from django model

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want a command for getting a query set from the model.
The SQL command will be like

```
SELECT teamName FROM TABLE WHERE userName=userName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
teamNameQuery=userInfo.objects.filter(userName=userName).values('teamName').first()
```

Comment: For completeness, please explain your answer, and provide a reference when you are copying someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrive list of field from model by using `values_list`

```
Model.Objects.filter(userName = userName).values_list('teamName')
```